# Save vim mapped key in Intellij

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, ideavim

I've a problem with vim plugin in Intellij:
if for example I map a command as follow:

```
:map <F2> i<CR><ESC>
```

I can use it without problem, I see it in Other Settings / Vim Emulation / 
Shortcut Conflicts.... as:

```
   Shortcut : F2
    IDE Action : Edit Group
    Handler : Vim
```

so everythings is ok, but when I restart Intellij shortcut is deleted: it doesn't appear in Shortcut Conflicts and it isn't on map list.

I'm on Windows 10, is there a way to save it?

Answer (score 3):

You can write your mappings in `~/.ideavimrc` file. ideavim will load the file when it starts. In fact the `~/.vimrc` will be loaded too.

I am not familiar with Windows OS, but the `~` means the user home directory. You should find the corresponding dir on windows system.

Comment: In order to load ~/.vimrc too, you have to put `source ~/.vimrc` into your ~/.ideavimrc.